# remapping separate keyboard device (with duplicate keys)

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

I wanted to have a small programmable second keyboard I can use for different games/applications. So I bought one with 8 keys - so far so good. But apparently it uses the same keys as my main keyboard (digit 1-8 on the upper part) so when I want to remap it via sharpkeys **both** keys will be remapped.

Is there a method to remap only the keys for the second keyboard? I am using windows 10.

**Update:**
I found out that it could be done with a driver intercept (but can't find one that I can use) or a controller between the usb connection but I am still looking for a cheaper/free method.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted the hardware seller (chinese company) and they send me some kind of driver/tool where can I achieve the wanted behaviour.